# Persist user data without external database

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, persistence

I'm still very new to iOS but I think I at least have a basic grasp around the sandbox and data persistence. I would just like to confirm something. I want to make an app that stores user favorites (just plist type data). The thing is, this is an in-house solution and I will be pushing updates to devices quite frequently. My question is, is it possible to persist the user information **without** storing that information in an external database?

The way I understood it was once you upload a new IPA and the user updates, the old IPA is completely gone which implies that the sandbox directory is completely overwritten which includes **any** type of locally persisted data within the app.

Am I wrong? Is storing the user favorites on an external database the only way to keep a user from losing their favorites when the app updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrect. When a user updates an app, the sandbox data is NOT wiped.

Can you imagine how much uproar there would be from the many millions of iOS users if their app data was lost every time they updated an app?

Keep data in the sandbox. It is safe as long as the app isn't deleted.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for setting me straight. So I guess the only time it's a worry is if you edit the data model itself in which the app would need to be reinstalled to align with the new data model? For example adding a new value to a core data model or something.

Comment: See the Core Data docs for info on dealing with schema changes.